# Microsoft Sync Framework Alternatives

Tags: synchronization

What do you use for data synchronization?

I have been working with Microsoft Sync Framework for a couple months now and I'm not sure if I like it. The concept is great but I've had trouble with remote sync. There is no remote file sync provider, but I did manage to write one with a lot of trouble. There is also no way to show progress that I am aware of on ADO.NET sync services.

I'm coming up with an error when two clients try to sync at the same time. "The metadata store is already in use." After all the sleepless nights trying to get a remote file sync provider working and now this error, I am now in search of alternatives.

Is there any better alternatives to MSF?

Does anyone know of any open source frameworks or samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Disconnected Service Agent Application Block from the Smart Client Software Factory:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc540752.aspx

It provides a store-and-forward mechanism for remote web service calls -- you could combine this with caching to acheive something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can now also use [Couchbase Lite for .NET](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-net).  :)

[Full Disclosure: I'm the guy who created the .NET version of Couchbase Lite.]